# Auto source a script after sudo su

Tags: unix, sudo, bashrc, su

I am working on a machine that has some user accounts that are dynamically generated, and therefore I can not user customize the `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

I frequently need to use these accounts to change some configurations; to do so I `sudo su` into them.

My issue is that on my user account I have configured a lot of aliases that I have come to use without even thinking about, aliases that do not exist for this `su`d user.

Is there a way, from my shell, to automatically source a specific file when only I `su` to a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply start your bash with the `--rcfile /path/to/script` flag. 
to be specific, use

```
sudo -u $USER bash --rcfile /path/to/file
```

make sure not to cover `bash --rcfile /path/to/file` by double quotes, because if so, sudo will not find the bash command.

You could also make a function containing that with the user as parameter `$1`

Comment: He there, I just tried this out but it does not seem to be working. I tried it with the given command however I do not have the pass of the user I am trying to become, I am using sudo. I tried prepending sudo to this command with no luck. `bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell`

Comment: Oh... no sorry, didn't read your question well. if you use sudo you better should use `sudo -u $USER bash --rcfile /path/to/file`. in that case you could function that like `sudo -u $1 bash --rcfile /path/to/file`

Comment: Awesome. You click [edit] to edit your answer, this is an acceptable solution.

Comment: yes, I did it, but before you texted that, I was editing another answer because the question was edited....