# While invoking bash without options -c or -s the first argument is a filename, how to execute it sourced?

Tags: bash, shell

While invoking bash without options -c or -s the first argument is a filename (see manpage bash).

In such a case bash executes that file and exits.

I just need this feature, yet that file has to be execuded sourced.

How to execute it sourced?

All my trials are successless. And with googling I have not found a way.

If I write the first argument like

```
". filename"
```

only

```
".
```

is taken as the first argument.

Even if I correctly handle single quotes in single quoted string, it does not work. E.g.

```
sudo su - root -c 'exec /bin/bash -- '"'"'. /tmp/file'"'"''
```

The error message is

```
/bin/bash: . /tmp/file: No such file or directory
```

Regards

== addendum 30.10.2023 20:35

I have made a test, if in that moment and under that conditions when my commandline in question runs, my file /tmp/file is really accessible.

And it is.

For this test I have replaced my commandline in question by following test-line

```
sudo su - root -c ' exec /bin/bash -c '"'"' ls -la --tine-style=long-iso /tmp/file '"'"' '
```

Regards

Comment: …by not invoking `bash`? Not sure what you’re attempting to accomplish here, but one thing’s for certain: A different Bash instance (invoked by `bash`) cannot affect its parent process.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You say "while invoking bash …". `bash whatever` creates a new process, *always*. You can source something in this new Bash with `bash -c '. ./somefile`, but what is the point? This will be sourced in the new Bash, so you can as well do `bash ./somefile`. To source `./somefile` in your current Bash you simply… well, literally source it in your current Bash: `. ./somefile`. What's wrong with this? **Or do you want to start an *interactive* Bash that sources a non-standard file before it displays the first prompt? and then lets the user use it interactively?**

Comment: `. /tmp/file` is shell code, not a pathname, so you do need `-c`. But again, why do you want to source the file? `/bin/bash` invoked inside `su` inside `sudo` will be a new Bash *anyway*, so you can simply give it the pathname (`/tmp/file`). Unless you want the new Bash to be and stay interactive; do you?

Comment: == 30.10.2023 21:00 Here short explanation of the background, since you cannot have in mind all what I wrote in last weeks. I use Kubuntu, KDE plama, do not use GUI, have under Konsole very may windows open. In each window runs bash as first-level shell for user kubuntu. And thereupon I create a second-level bash shell for user root. I work as root. On the bottom line there are the usual tabs for the windows. Withe the mouse click I switch between windows. Now for some reasons (I have often asked for help)   in the bottom line one tab for a window vanishs, and the window vanishs. Sometimes

Comment: Sometimes only the second level shell is closed, exited  and sometimes both levels shells are gone. Thus very often I have to recreate the shells. To remake all my special settings is a hard and long work. Only a few of the many settings are stored by the system. Thus I live for making scripts to be a help. My commandline in question is in this script: called in first-level shell. To make settings in first-level shell. To create the second-level shell. To switch to second-level shell. To continue running and make all settings for second-level shell and thus to reastablish fully operat* Regards

Comment: Is the "second-level shell" supposed to be interactive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto source a script after `sudo su`](https://superuser.com/q/951918/432690). Does `--rcfile` help?

Comment: == 2023-10-31 20:30 my understanding of what manpage bash says is now better. And I have found the cause and solution to my problem, for which I asked for help:  So in this way as bash is invoked, bash takes the first argument as a file. Thus the argument is only being read (not executed). Thus the argument cannot begin with a dot, like ". filename". To achieve what I want I have to do: bash has to get as argument "myfile". The contents of "myfile" can then be either "myscript" (for non-sourced) or ". myscript" (for sourced). Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble and your answers. Regards. Anton Wessel.

Comment: == 01.11.2023 00:30 The problem is not solved, I have to make more investigations

Comment: @AntonWessel What are you trying accomplish here? This sounds very much like an XY problem.

Comment: Please, can someone say, where to find a full documentation to this item in manpage bash: "If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands (see Shell Scripts). When Bash is invoked in this fashion, ... , Bash reads and executes commands from this file, then exits." - This does not mention any restrictions on the commands, thus the bash builtin "source" should work, but I have not yet found a way to run the code in this file sourced. Please examples. Regards.

Comment: What is the point of sourcing a file inside a new Bash? Unless you want the shell to stay and be interactive after sourcing the file. So I'm asking for the third time: do you want to start an interactive Bash that sources a non-standard file before it displays the first prompt? and then lets the user use it interactively?

Comment: == 02.11.2023 14:20 Thanks for your answer. The intention of my script is to automatically what I am doing by hand: After having created in KDEplasma its Konsole a new terminal window, in the first-level shell of user kubuntu to create a second-level for user root by

Comment: == 02.11.2023 14:20 Thanks for your answer. The intention of my script is to automatically do what I am doing by hand: After having created in KDE plasma its Konsole a new terminal window, therein in the first-level shell of user kubuntu to create a second-level for user root by "su -" or alike. Then in this second-level shell to make configutations and let this second-level shell be the normal interactive shell for all future works of user root. (see my explanation of 30.10.2023). Regards.

Comment: It was so hard to get one crucial bit of information from you here. Literally one bit: yes/no. Starting from my first comment I keep asking: do you want to start an interactive Bash that sources a non-standard file before it displays the first prompt? And finally you say that "this second-level shell be the normal interactive shell". At last. :) So `--rcfile` from the accepted answer to [this already linked question](https://superuser.com/q/951918/432690) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It may be as easy as `sudo bash --rcfile /tmp/file`

Comment: == 04.11.2023 11:20 comment 1 of x: sorry for unsufficient information from me. I thought that from the very beginning of my writing the goal was evident: to provide a bash shell to user root as it is automatically provided to user kubuntu when in KDE Konsole a new window is opened. Of course the shell for root has to have the same capabilities as for kubuntu but with root permissions. (Please wai for comments number 2 of x etc). Regards

Comment: == 09.11.2023 19:35 comment 2 of x: Having had interim other problems with bash (code runnable since tens of years now failed), I can come slowly back to the original  problem of this my post. -- Thank you very much for your writing about bash's option --rcfile. Now it is needed to explicate that we have two different aspects in regard of sourcing or not-sourcing of a code. One aspect is: after a shell was invoked, the shell can run a code in a script sourced or not-sourced. With using --rcfile <myfilename>, bash runs the code in <myfilename> sourced, instead of

Comment: == 09.11.2023 20:10 comment 3 of x: , instead of without option --rcfile bash runs sourced its initialisation files .basrc or ..bash_profile etc. The other aspect is: on the way to invoke the shell, the code for doing all for invoking, this code to run sourced. This aspect was my aim on my way before you remembered on --rcfile. On this my way I got tied up over the question of bash being invoked without option -c and -o so as bash to take the first argument as filename and executes the code therein. Thereby I stumbled over the seem that this code cannot be run sourced.

Comment: == 09.11.2023 21:00 comment 4 if x: It seemed that this code cannot be run sourced. It turned out that 1. the code can be run sourced (if the filename is prepended by ".  "),  and 2. that other behavior is different for this case causing that my usual tests for if sourced or not-sourced, which are based on contents of $0,  yield the wrong result, that not-sourced. I think my code could be helpfull for someone  and I intend to present my code as answer to my question. And the second, good way with --rcfile I have to study further. Will take long. Thanks and Regards.